# Apex - Interactive Report some rows read only

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a Interactive Report with addresses and the possibility to modify addresses and create new ones with the "Link to Single Row View". 
Now I have archived addresses and not archived ones. And I need the archived ones to be in read only, so the End user can't change them. I know I can change the whole Interactive Report to read only, but can I change only some specific rows to read only?
Thanx for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement recently where I had an interactive report where the link needs to go to an "Edit" page for some records, and a "View" page for others. The way I solved this was as follows:

1. Set up the link to always go to the "View" page for the selected record, with `REQUEST` set to `'EDIT'`.
2. On the "View" page, add a Before Header Branch that redirects to the "Edit" page. Add a condition to the Branch so it only fires if Request = `'EDIT'` and the selected record is editable. For all other cases, the user is left on the "View" page.

This way, only records that are Editable are redirected to the Edit page for them.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, first of all thanx for the answer, but I think I don't get all of it. I change the Link Column in the Interactive Report in the Report Attributes to "Link to a single row view"?! But where can I fill the REQUEST field? Cause when I change it to "Link to a single row view", there isn't such field anymore. Or did I miss something? Do I have to change it in the Columns Attributes?

Comment: No, set it to Link to Custom target.